# What are the chances of admission in to Graduate School in USA after being informally interviewed by a Professor on Skype?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, interview

Two days ago I was interviewed by a Professor I mentioned in my Statement of Purpose for application of MS in CS in USA.
It was for 10 minutes, this time had been predetermined by the school. The questions were very informal.

What does it mean? It's been 2 days and I've heard no reply yet.

Comment: Not every university will have an interview as part of their application process. Apparently, this one does. We can't know this for sure, but it is likely that the professor who talked to you gives his feedback (what he thought about your chat) to his colleagues, and it will be part of the overall information about you leading to a decision. In the future, to know more than internet guesses, ask politely at the end "I enjoyed talking you! What will be next steps, and how long roughly until I hear back from you?"

Comment: There is no reason to think that an interview will change the time when a decision will be made.  Another reason for a "live" interview, even if it is short, might be to gauge how good your English is.

Comment: I don't think there is anything we can conclude from this.

Comment: 2 days is way to little time for anything...

Comment: If someone told you the chances are on average 72.68%, what would you do with that information?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any way to guess your "chances" of admission, and it's not productive to try.  Just wait patiently; when the decision is made, you'll be notified.  In the meantime, spend your mental energy on something more useful than trying to predict the result.

At most US universities, graduate admission decisions are made by a committee of faculty.  You had an interview with one professor, but she probably doesn't get to decide for herself whether or not to admit you.  Rather, she will report her impressions to her colleagues on the admission committee.  After they have reviewed all the applications, they will discuss them and  decide who will be admitted.  This takes time, certainly more than two days.  I'd expect it will be at least several more weeks before you hear anything.  So be patient!